# Functional approach to splitting list into sub lists

Tags: functional-programming, f#

Here is my functional approach to split a list into sub lists, each having non-decreasing  numbers, so the input

\$[1; 2; 3; 2; 4; 1; 5;]\$

computes to

\$[[1; 2; 3]; [2; 4]; [1; 5]]\$

The code works, but I need a while to understand it.  I would prefer a solution that is more clear. Is there a way to make this more elegant or readable?  Everything is allowed, F# mutables as well. Or do I just get used more to functional code reading?

The subsets are called "run"s in the code below.

```
// returns a single run and the remainder of the input
let rec takerun input =
    match input with
    | [] -> [], []
    | [x] -> [x], []
    | x :: xr -> if x < xr.Head then 
                     let run, remainder = takerun xr
                     x :: run, remainder
                 else [x], xr

// returns the list of all runs
let rec takeruns input =
    match takerun input with
    | run, []  -> [run]
    | run, rem -> run :: takeruns rem


let runs = takeruns [1; 2; 3; 2; 4; 1; 5;]
> val runs : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [2; 4]; [1; 5]]
```

**Edit:**

Considering the helpful feedback I ended up with this reusable code. And got more used to functional programming, comparing imperative alternatives I meanwhile find the pure functional approach more readable. This version is good readable, although not tail recursive. For the small lists I had to deal with, readability was preferred.

```
// enhance List module
module List = 

    // splits list xs into 2 lists, based on f(xn, xn+1)
    let rec Split f xs =
        match xs with
        | []  -> [],  []
        | [x] -> [x], []
        | x1 :: x2 :: xr when f x1 x2 -> [x1], x2 :: xr // split on first f(xn, xn+1)
        | x :: xr -> let xs1, xs2 = Split f xr
                     x :: xs1, xs2

// Now takruns becomes quite simple
let rec takeruns input =
    match List.Split (>) input with
    | run, []  -> [run]
    | run, rem -> run :: takeruns rem

let runs = takeruns [1; 2; 3; 2; 4; 1; 5;]
```

Comment: "Consecutive" would mean two integers (a, b) such that b = a + 1. It doesn't change the essence of the problem, though.

Comment: thx for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version that uses `List.foldBack` and `List.pairwise`

```
let split lst =
    let folder (a, b) (cur, acc) = 
        match a with
        | _ when a < b -> a::cur, acc
        | _ -> [a], cur::acc

    let result = List.foldBack folder (List.pairwise lst) ([List.last lst], []) 
    (fst result)::(snd result)

printfn "%A" (split [1; 2; 3; 2; 2; 4; 1; 5;])
```

Answer (score 4):

Haskell:

```
import Data.List.HT -- or Data.List.Grouping

takeruns xs@(x:xss) = map (map fst) pss
  where pss = segmentAfter (uncurry (>)) $ zip xs xss
```

**EDIT**
Example:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
xss = [2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
zip xs xss = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 4), (4, 1)]
uncurry (>) (1, 2) == 1 > 2 = False
segmentAfter ... = [
    [(1, 2) /* False */, (2, 3) /* False */, (3, 2) /* True */],
    [(2, 4) /* False */, (4, 1) /* True */],
    []
]
map (map fst) (segmentAfter ...) = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4], []]
```

And, it turns out that my function is wrong :)
Correct version:

```
takeruns xs = map (map snd) pss
  where pss = segmentAfter (uncurry (>)) $ zip (minBound:xs) xs
```

Comment: This is not exactly a helpful code review. At least you should try and explain the solution in haskell and in how far it could be applied to other functional language as well.

Comment: @ChrisWue I really don't know what to add to my answer. TS asked for "more readable or elegant version" -- my amost one-liner is not very readable, but probably the shortest. Initially TS mentioned Haskell

Comment: thx for the helpful input. i realize that plain f# simply lacks some reusable functional basics, like Haskell's segmentAfter which can be found at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.1/docs/src/Data-List-HT-Private.html

Comment: leventov, perhaps you could explain your code a bit more? **How** does it do what it does?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg see edit

Comment: Better :) Now you found that the original was incorrect as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Since there is only one solution using sequences and one in Haskell, I thought that I still might post my code:

```
let partition list =
    let rec aux =
        function
        | trg,acc,[] -> acc::trg
        | trg,a::acc,x::xs when x<a 
            -> aux ((a::acc)::trg,[x],xs)
        | trg,acc,x::xs -> aux (trg,x::acc,xs)
    aux ([],[],list)|> List.map (List.rev) |> List.rev
```

Of course, running through the list twice as in the last line is bad (performance wise), however this could be easily solved by a custom `revMap` function that reverses and maps at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Using List.foldBack

```
let insert e state = 
    match state with
    | cur::rest ->
        match cur with
        | h::_ when e < h ->  (e::cur)::rest // add e to current list
        | _ -> [e]::state   // start a new list 
    | _ -> [[e]]

List.foldBack insert [1;2;3;2;4;1;5;] []

val insert : e:'a -> state:'a list list -> 'a list list when 'a : comparison
val it : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [2; 4]; [1; 5]]
```